# Connectwise API Powershell Module question

Tags: powershell

Has anyone used this cmdlet from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConnectWiseManageAPI/0.4.9.0?

new-cwmcompanyconfiguration

My issues come from it asking for some required parameters as hashtables. I'm not quite sure what I need to have as the value. Unfortunately, I've been unable to find any code examples of this being used online anywhere.

My example:

```
$Company = '250'
$name = 'API Test Device'
$type = "Servers - Linux"
$info  = "test"
$IPaddress = 'test'
$ostype = 'test'
$serialnumber = 'test'


New-CWMCompanyConfiguration -company $company -name $name -type $type -_info $info -ipAddress $IPaddress -osType $ostype -serialNumber $serialnumber -verbose
```

it wants the company, type and info as hashtables, not sure what key/value pairs to feed it

Comment: Wow the documentation for this module is atrocious. From the Get-Help for that command: `DESCRIPTION {{ Fill in the Description }}` - the same thing for its example

Comment: Agreed, I'm scraping to find people who may have used it before so that I can pick their brain.

Comment: have you tried defining those 3 variables as `$company = @{"company"="250"}` and `$type = @{"type"="API Test Device"}` and `$info = @{"info"="test"}` with the key as the name of the paramter

Comment: That didn't work but it put me on the correct path. Using the return format from Get-CWMConfiguration I was able to see the expected hash values.

Answer (score 1):

I had to check the formatting of a configuration returned from Get-CWMCompanyConfiguration

```
Example of what worked:
$company = @{"id"="250"}
$name = 'API Test Device'
$type = @{"name"="Servers - Linux"}
$IPaddress = "123.123.123.123"
$ostype = "Test"
$serialnumber = "Test"
New-CWMCompanyConfiguration -company $company -name $name -type $type -ipAddress $IPaddress -osType $ostype -serialNumber $serialnumber
```